# Getting the definition of the tables and columns via a SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database and a lot of tables inside it. I wrote definition into the each table and column's definition part. And now using query I want to see all table and columns definition.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SqlServer.

```
SELECT obj.name, cols.name as columnname
from dbname.sys.objects as obj
inner join dbname.sys.columns as cols
on obj.object_id = cols.object_id
where obj.type='U'
```

Answer (score 5):

try this to get the definition of table in SQL...

> sp_help 'tableName'

example `sp_help 'MyTable'`

We can also do same thing as

```
exec sp_help 'MyTable'
```

Because **sp_help** is a pre define *stored processor* and we can execute stored processor using "**exec**" keyword or also can use "**execute**" keyword

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bass query that can list info from the colums and tables in SQL server. Just add the columns you need from each system table.

```
SELECT 
  t.name table_name,
, c.name column_name
From sys.tables AS t
Inner Join sys.columns c 
  On t.Object_ID = c.Object_ID
```

Comment: i tried it. when i execute the query i can see each table and its columns , but there is no definition part of the tables and its columns even i start to write select * ...

Comment: Hm, not sure where those are kept if not those tables. Take a look here and see if this helps. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9eaa58b6-6024-4925-858c-a31a919696af/how-to-get-column-description-of-a-table-in-sql-server-2000-programmatically?forum=sqldocumentation

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

OR

for more detailed table information

```
EXEC sp_help [Your Table_Name]
```

Comment: i tried , and i get a lot of informations about tables and its columns but no definition information..

Comment: @Taha Karaca...what do you expect by saying definition??

Comment: tables  and its columns description i want to list

Comment: when we right click a table and select design. There is table properties and column properites. In this part , we can write some informations into the description parts of the table and its columns. So i want to list these descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for extended descriptions:

```
SELECT 
  OBJECT_NAME(major_id) TableName,(select name from sys.columns c where c.object_id=major_id and c.column_id=minor_id) ColumnName,*
FROM 
  sys.extended_properties
WHERE 
  name='MS_Description' AND minor_id>0 and class=1
```